# Wishlist in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, wishlist, php-7

How to get configurable option value of added product in wishlist in magento2.

```
$collection = $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory->create()
                    ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId);

            $wishlistData = [];

            foreach ($collection as $_item) {
            $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($_item->getProductId());
            echo "<pre>";print_r($product->getAttributeText('size'));
            }exit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that using the code:

> $product->getAttributeText('size')

You cannot get your select size options.

`$_item->getBuyRequest()->getSuperAttribute()` for getting selected options.